# Rewrite address bar without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a host in my university's http server under the domain: `university.com/~username`

Now, I also have a domain on: `mydomain.net` with GoDaddy

I want to know if it is possible to have a subdomain:
`university.mydomain.net` that basically redirects to
`university.com/~username`.

Now, the trick here is that if I want to access
`university.com/~username/subdir` via `university.mydomain.net/subdir`
the address bar in the browser shows: `university.mydomain.net/subdir` no
matter if I access it via `university.com/~username` or `university.mydomain.net`

The problem with using permanent redirect with masking in GoDaddy, then if
I am in the dir `university.mydomain.net/subdir` and go to the subsubdir
`university.mydomain.net/subdir/subsubdir` then the browser still shows `university.mydomain.net/subdir`

And about CNAMEs or other kind of register in GoDaddy, I really have no idea
what to do (this is my first domain) and I don't even know if I have the rights
in my university server to make a difference.

I tried with a RewriteRule in a `.htaccess` file, but this always tries to
redirect (no matter what flag I use) to `university.mydomain.com/subdir`
while the only thing I want to do is that the address bar shows the direction
without following it.

I really don't even know if this is possible somehow. Sorry if it's an stupid
question, I'm very new with domains and those stuffs.

Comment: You'll have to use **mod_proxy** and `P` flag instead of `L` in your rule

Comment: Still try to follow the link. I just want to show it in the address bar without following it (probably what I want is not possible)

Comment: If you want to "internally" rewrite `university.com/~username` -> `university.mydomain.net` then it is **not possible** since (i guess) you don't have any access to `university.com` server configuration. But if you want the opposite, then it's possible

Comment: The first one is precisely what I want :( No luck then. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can still ask to `university.com` owner if `htaccess` files are enabled (and also mod_rewrite / mod_proxy). This way you could do what you want

Comment: htaccess files are enabled. But I don't know how to configure it so it does what I want :/ Redirecting is not what I want, I just want that when someone access `university.mydomain.com/[subdir]` it shows `university.com/~unsername/[subdir]` content but `university.mydomain.com/[subdir]` in the address bar. And when someone access `university.com/~username/[subdir]` it shows the content of that site but in the address bar shows `university.mydomain.com/[subdir]` (subdir being optional). With masking by GoDaddy the problem is that it remains static when browsing a directory

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled (I used although not with my expected result). The other one I don't know even how to check it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the `CNAME` you need to add you subdomain entry (in the Godaddy DNS management console)

`university.mydomain.net`  points to `@`

and in your host the `@` might be pointing to the IP address where your university server is running.

Then in your apache vhost config, you would need to have rewrite rule like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^university.mydomain.net(:80)?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://university.com/~username/$1  [P,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^university.com(:80)?$
RewriteRule ^/~username/(.*) http://university.mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself clear. What I want is the opposite. I want `http://university.com/~username/subdir` to be rewritten in the bar as `http://university.mydomain.net/subdir` (but without changing the content of the page, this still has to show the content of `http://university.com/~username/subdir`)

Comment: Ok. Maybe what I want is not possible. I don't have access to the apache conf (I only can create a `.htaccess` file). And if I create a register in GoDaddy to the ip of my university server I access the root there (`university.com`), and I want `university.mydomain.com` to access to the subdirectory at `university.com/~ccardellino`.

Is possible to only tell the `.htaccess` file to change the name in the bar to `university.mydomain.com` without trying to actually follow the link (that way I just use redirect in GoDaddy)

Comment: Check this out .. hope this is useful..
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name

Comment: It's what I've been doing, with mask, but it's not the same, as it keeps the mask everytime, so when I go to `university.mydomain.com/subdir` and then from there access a subsubdir like `university.mydomain.com/subdir/subsubdir`, the bar still shows `university.mydomain.com/subdir`. I'm guessing what I want is just not possible with the little privileges I have. Thanks anyway for the help. Sorry to bother.